# Research in applied algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, soft-question, computational-group-theory

I am in my final year of my doctoral study in Mathematics, where my research topic is $p$-groups, specifically classification of $p$-groups by [coclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coclass).  My work involves a great deal of computation in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/). I really like programming and have knowledge in *C*, *MatLab* and *Mathematica*.

So far all my research is in pure math but for my post-doctoral research I would like to research some *applications* of algebra/group theory.  I don't have sufficient knowledge in this regard though I have heard that genomics and crystallography both rely on applied algebra.

I would appreciate learning of some areas/fields where I can apply computational applied algebra as well as institutions/centers and/or scholars whom I could contact. Regarding location, I am open to any place but in specific I am looking for some positions in USA & Canada, Europe & UK or in Australia & New Zealand.

Comment: I am not very sure if this is on topic here..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sorry for the post. But if you think some part of the question can be edited to make it on-topic, please feel free to advise.

Comment: I am not an experienced user here... I do not know how to make it more suitable... I hope some one else will help...

Comment: @David G. Stork Thanks for the edit. The post is much better now.

Comment: Perhaps you would get more useful responses if you specified geographical areas where you would be interested in pursuing postdoctoral research? Or are you looking worldwide?

Comment: @MarkGrant Thanks. I will add geographical locations.

Comment: I view such listing of institutions as opinion-based and therefore problematic on this site.

Comment: And Canada is really out of bounds as a geographic area of interest?

Comment: @YCor I had the impression the OP is asking for information on what people do in various institutions, not about any ranking of the people or the groups at those institutions. Hence I don't see that this is really "opinion-based"

Comment: @usermath: Just a guess -- may it be that your advisor is Bettina Eick?

Comment: @KConrad Edited. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: @StefanKohl very close :) I also work with Prof. Eick but she is not my advisor, her student is my advisor in Australia.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks. Yes, I am just asking for information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the UK, there is the [Applied Algebra and Geometry Research Network](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/Mathematics/Research/Algebra-and-Analysis/AppliedAlgebraGeometry.aspx). You could browse the list of former speakers and abstracts for ideas.

The University of St Andrews has a [strong group](http://www-maths.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/pg/pure/Algebra/members.php) in Combinatorics and Algebra, with some members (such as [Rosemary Bailey](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~rab/)) working on computations and applications.

In Ireland, [Graham Ellis](http://www.nuigalway.ie/our-research/people/mathematics-statistics-and-applied-mathematics/grahamellis/)'s group at NUI Galway is very active in the field of computational algebra.

In Leipzig, Germany there is the Max Planck Institute for Mathematics in the Sciences, where in particular [Bernd Sturmfels' group](https://www.mis.mpg.de/nlalg/research.html) works on applications of algebra to non-linear models

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. I will browse through the links you provided. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! In St Andrews please see also [Centre for Interdisciplinary Research in Computational Algebra (CIRCA)](https://www-circa.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 5):

A lot of "algebra" is happening in programming language theory and practice nowadays, with knowledge of category theory and type theory really beneficial. Practical applications involve creating certified for correctness programs, and certifying existing programs for correctness.
You might have heard about computer-certified proofs of theorems, such as [Odd Order Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem) - this essentially falls into the same domain.
(Here is the [announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119094854/http://www.msr-inria.fr/news/feit-thomson-proved-in-coq/)).

For something completely different: symmetries are used in optimisation and machine learning, to reduce dimension etc. And, certainly, there is a lot of algebra in computational (algebraic and "usual") geometry.

Yet another applied topic with a lot of algebra is cryptography and coding theory; among the topics mentioned, it is probably the closest to finite group theory.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have heard about computer-proofs. That is really interesting. Unfortunately I have no exposure to type theory or category theory. However symmetries are more close to my research topic probably. Though I am open to learn new things. Do you have any suggestion regarding any specific institution or person? Thanks again.